# Pandas Keyerror in Simple calling of array elements

Tags: pandas

I am loading a .csv from Pandas. It has a column for country, month, year, and date. Since I'm only interested in these, I overwrite the imported dataframe with a simpler version.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
idx_USA = df['Country'] == 'United States'
df = df.loc[:,['Year','Month','Date']]
print(df[:4])
```

This yeilds

```
   Year Month Date
1  2007    1   1
2  2004     10   2
4  1999     10   14
7  2000     10   5
```

Now,oddly, when I try to access the years in a loop, I get a keyerror! This is so simple-- what is going on? Thanks.

```
for i in range(1,N):
    print "Yr = ", df['Year'][i]


Yr =  2007
Yr =  2004
Yr = 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testimport.py", line 19, in <module>
    print "Yr = ", df['Year'][i]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 491, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1032, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
  File "index.pyx", line 97, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2957)
  File "index.pyx", line 105, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2772)
  File "index.pyx", line 149, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3498)
  File "hashtable.pyx", line 382, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6930)
  File "hashtable.pyx", line 388, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6871)
KeyError: 3
```

Comment: Your index does not have 3 in it, this is quite clear in your data output, why do you want to iterate over them?

Comment: Ahhh I see, so this index is not like using numpy dtype, where the index corresponds to that particular element... So how can I renumber these indices to go from 1 to N? Thanks!

Comment: You could just call [`df = df.reindex()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) this will set the index to start from `0`

Comment: You'd be better off iterating over `df.itertuples()` if you really need to iterate over the dataframe

Comment: Also you can specify the columns you are interested in when reading the csv `pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols=['Year','Month','Date'])` if you are only interested in these, see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#io-read-csv-table

Comment: Thanks! So df = df.reindex() results in the same indexing... Hmmm

Comment: Sorry I meant `df = df.reset_index()` this will reset index (i.e. drop current one) and create a new one starting from `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of resetting the index you can just iterate through the underlying array.

```
arr = df['year']
for i in range(1,N):
    print arr[i]
```

Comment: Also just to make sure that you know range(1,N) won't go through every element in the array as it will start with the second one in the format I gave you - I was copying what you had in your question.  should be `for i in range(len(arr)):` or `for each in arr:`  or to get index val pairs `for i,each in enumerate(arr):`